# Unsubscribe link in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have an unsubscribe link in the emails that we send out from  marketing cloud. But when we click on the subscriber link, that navigates to the  preference centre and that gives an option only to update the details. There is no Unsubscribe button in there and the contacts are not getting unsubscribed.

I have got the Unsub link  registered from Marketing cloud

http://click.info.abc.com.au/unsub_center.aspx?s=%%ex2;subscriberid%%&j=%%ex2;jobid%%&mid=%%ex2;MemberID%%&lid=%%ex2;listid%%&jb=%%ex2;_JobSubscriberBatchID%%&ju=%%ex2;joburlid%%

Now the issue here is

1. I am not able to locate this page as this is  not available in Cloud Pages
2. I want to make the Unsubscribe link work so that when  the user clicks on the link  Unsubscribe happens  from the All Subscriber list.

What I am thinking is to create a new Cloud page and try to update the  list with Unsubscribe. But I am not quite sure on the code that I need to write behind the page to update the list.

Can anyone give me pointers ?

Comment: I cannot answer your first question regarding why you land on a different site than expected. However, if you want to write your own logic, here is the start: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/unsubEvent.htm

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud requires to have a link to the Profile Center. You can include it in your email by clicking on  [image] then selecting Profile Center:

[image]

Otherwise, if you want to create one click unsubscribe button, you can use this AMPScript code:

```
%%[
    VAR @sid, @jid, @listid, @batchid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @lue_Response, @lue_Status, @lue_Error


    SET @emailaddr = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
    SET @emailName = AttributeValue("emailname_") 
    SET @subKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
    SET @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
    SET @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")

    /* Set the listId here */
    SET @listid = '21'

    SET @reason = "PUT THE UNSUBSCRIBING REASON HERE"

    SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @subKey)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

    SET @lue_Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
    SET @lue_Status = Field(@lue_Response,"StatusMessage")
    SET @lue_Error = Field(@lue_Response,"ErrorCode")


]%%
```

Don't forget to update some details in the code as described in comments. You can find the AllSubscribers list id by going to Email Studio > Subscribers > AllSubscribers > Properties and grab the List ID.